# Array with dynamic length for simulation

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL, is there a way to have a dynamically sized array for simulation?

I would like to use it as a list, i.e., the testbench repeatedly appends values to the end, and then iterates over the list. The length of the array is not statically known.

Comment: Yes. The easiest way is to determine the length at runtime,  refer to the array via an access type (pointer) and allocate it with `new`. If it needs to continually grow, you will need to reallocate,copy atd free the old one.

Comment: But note that you can't create signals this way - only variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array utility of VUnit (https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/tree/master/vunit/vhdl/array) provides the functionality you're looking for. It provides a protected type `array_t` which has a method `append` that does the dynamic sizing. Here is some code from the testbench for this utility (https://github.com/VUnit/vunit/blob/master/vunit/vhdl/array/test/tb_array.vhd) that exemplifies the `append` method

```
variable arr : array_t;
...
arr.init;
...
arr.append(11);
check_equal(arr.length, 1);
check_equal(arr.get(0), 11);

arr.append(7);
check_equal(arr.length, 2);
check_equal(arr.get(1), 7);
```